# Question regarding Gambler's Ruin

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

Consider a gambling process $(X_n)_{n∈\mathbb{N}}$ on the state space $S = {0, 1, . . . , N}$, with probability
$p$, resp. $q$, of moving up, resp. down, at each time step. For $x = 0, 1, . . . , N$, let $τ_x$
denote the first hitting time, $τ_x := \inf\{n ≥ 0 : X_n = x\}$

Let $p_x := P(τ_{x+1} < τ_0 | X_0 = x), x = 0, 1, . . . , N − 1$

Explain why $p_x$ satisfies the recursion $p_x = p + qp_{x−1}p_x$ for $x = 1, . . . , N − 1$.

I apply the first step analysis, whereby

$P(τ_{x+1} < τ_0 | X_0 = x) = P(τ_{x+1} < τ_0 | X_0 = x_1, X_1=x+1) \cdot P(X_1=x+1 |X_0 = x) + P(τ_{x+1} < τ_0 | X_0 = x_1, X_1=x-1) \cdot P(X_1=x-1 |X_0 = x)$

By the time homogeneous property, the equation reduces to,

$P(τ_{x+1} < τ_0 | X_0 = x+1) \cdot P(X_1=x+1 |X_0 = x) + P(τ_{x+1} < τ_0 | X_0 =x-1) \cdot P(X_1=x-1 |X_0 = x)$

Given that initial state is $x+1$, we have already "hit" $x+1$ before hitting $0$. So the equation is now

$1 \cdot p + P(τ_{x+1} < τ_0 | X_0 =x-1) \cdot q$

Now all left to do is to find $P(τ_{x+1} < τ_0 | X_0 =x-1)$

The Event $\{τ_{x+1} < τ_0 \}$ given that $X_0 =x-1$ can be pictured as paths with the following trends in the picture below.

[image]

I think the graph on the right correctly portrays the 2 general trends of the outcomes in the event.

It can be described as the paths starting at $x_1$, going up and down in any way except reaching $0$ before hitting $x+1$, and then eventually hitting either the absorption state $0$ or $N$.

But, i was told that we should IGNORE the presence absorption state $N$ and do the following,

Consider the graph on the left,

First treat $x$ as an absorption state and thus the green line has probability $p_{x_1}$.

Then treat $x+1$ as an absorption state and thus the blue line has the probability $p_{x}$. It stops here since it is an absorption state.

Is the above approach valid? It seems very strange as $0$ and $N$ are defined to be the absorption states in the gambling process.

If the above approach is valid, why so? (Edit: DEFINITELY NOT, Why did the person even tell me this).

If not, what is the proper approach here? (Edit: The accepted answer).

Comment: If I understand correctly, the way you defined $\tau_x$, the event $\{\tau_x < \tau_0\}$ means the process hits state $x$ before hitting 0. (The first time we hit $x$ is smaller than the first time we hit $0$.) So what is confusing?

Comment: Which also mean that we hit $x$ before hitting $0$, which includes outcomes of hitting $x$ and eventually hitting $0$, and outcomes of hitting $x$ and eventually hitting $N$.

Comment: Which seems fine to me, what is the question? (By the way "which also means that we hit x before hitting 0" is exactly what I wrote! I think this is the precise meaning of that event.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us write $\mathbb P_x(\cdots) = \mathbb P(\cdots \mid X_0 =x)$. Let $$A_{x+1} = \{\tau_{x+1} < \tau_0 \}=\{\text{hit $x+1$ before 0}\}$$ be the desired event. We have
\begin{align*}
p_x = \mathbb P_x(A_{x+1}) &= \mathbb P_x(X_1 = x+1) \mathbb P(A_{x+1} \mid X_1 = x+1)+
\mathbb P_x(X_1 = x-1) \mathbb P(A_{x+1} \mid X_1 = x-1) \\
&= p \cdot 1 + q \;\mathbb P(A_{x+1} \mid X_1 = x-1) \\
&= p \cdot 1 + q \mathbb P_{x-1}(A_{x+1}) \\
\end{align*}
It only remains to compute the probability of hitting $x+1$ before zero  starting at $x-1$. But this is equivalent to hitting $x$ before zero starting at $x-1$, then hitting $x+1$ before zero as if we started again from $x$, and by strong Markov property these two events are independent (this is hand-waving, see details below!), hence the probability is $p_{x-1} p_x$.

If you want more details:
\begin{align}
 \mathbb P_{x-1}(\tau_{x+1} <\tau_0) &\stackrel{(a)}{=} \mathbb P_{x-1} (\tau_{x} < \tau_0, \tau_{x+1} < \tau_0) \\
&\stackrel{(b)}{=} \mathbb P_{x-1} (\tau_{x} < \tau_0) \,\mathbb P( \tau_{x+1} < \tau_0 \mid \tau_x < \tau_0, X_0 = x-1) \\
&\stackrel{(c)}{=}\mathbb P_{x-1} (\tau_{x} < \tau_0)\, \mathbb P_x( \tau_{x+1} < \tau_0).
\end{align}
Equality (a) is since if you start at $x-1$, you have to hit $x$ before $x+1$, that is 
$$\{\tau_{x+1} < \tau_0\} \cap \{X_0 = x-1\} \subset \{\tau_{x} < \tau_0\} \cap \{X_0 = x-1\}.$$

**More details:** Equality (b) above is basic conditional probability: $$\mathbb P(A_x \cap A_{x+1} \mid X_0 = x-1) = \mathbb P(A_x  \mid X_0 = x-1)\, \mathbb P(A_{x+1} \mid A_{x} \cap \{X_0 = x-1\}).$$
Equality (c) is tricky. Let us unpack:
We can write 
$$\{\tau_{x} < \tau_0\} = \{\tau_x < \infty,\, \tau_0 = \infty\} \cup \{\tau_x < \tau_0 < \infty\}$$
and these two events are disjoint. However, note that both imply that $\tau_x$ is finite, that is, we hit state $x$ at some point. Now, let us define $X'_n := X_{\tau_x + n},\; n\ge 0$ and let $\tau'_{x}$ be the hitting time of state $x$ in this  new process $\{X'_n\}$ (similar to $\tau_x$ which is the hitting time of $x$ by $\{X_n\}$). Also note that $\{X'_n\}$ is well-defined on the event $\tau_x < \infty$.

Let $B_x = \{\tau_x < \tau_0, \, X_0=x-1\}$. We want to calculate $\mathbb P (\tau_{x+1} < \tau_0 \mid B_x)$. As argued above, on $B_x$, $\tau_x$ is finite, that is, $B_x \subset \{\tau_x < \infty\}$. Given $B_x$, considering the first times $X'_n$ and $X_n$ hit $x+1$, by definition, we have $\tau_{x+1} = \tau_x + \tau'_{x+1}$. Similarly, on $B_x$, $\tau_0 = \tau_x + \tau'_0$. Thus,
\begin{align}
  \mathbb P (\tau_{x+1} < \tau_0 \mid B_x) &= 
  \mathbb P (\tau_{x+1} < \tau_0 \mid B_x \cap \{\tau_x < \infty\}) \\ &=
  \mathbb P (\tau'_{x+1}+\tau_x < \tau_0'+\tau_x \mid B_x \cap \{\tau_x < \infty\})  \\
  &= \mathbb P (\tau'_{x+1} < \tau'_0 \mid B_x \cap \{\tau_x < \infty\}) \\
&\stackrel{(d)}{=} \mathbb P (\tau'_{x+1} < \tau'_0 \mid B_x \cap \{\tau_x < \infty, X'_0 = x\}) \\
&\stackrel{(e)}{=} \mathbb P (\tau'_{x+1} < \tau'_0 \mid \{\tau_x < \infty, X'_0 = x\}) \\
&\stackrel{(f)}{=} \mathbb P (\tau_{x+1} < \tau_0 \mid X_0 = x) = p_x
\end{align}
where (d) is true by definition of $\tau_x$ (assuming $\tau_x < \infty$) since $X'_n = X_{\tau_x} = x$, and (e) and (f) follow from strong Markov property: Given $\tau_x < \infty, X'_0 = y$, the process $\{X'_n\}$ is independent of $X_1,\dots,X_{\tau_x}$ and has the same distribution as $\{X_n\}$ with $X_0 = y$. Note that $B_x$ only depends on $X_1,\dots,X_{\tau_x}$ (there should be no state 0 in there) hence using independence clause of strong Markov, can be dropped (equality (e)).

Comment: I have been thinking about it and i was wrong about the definition of $p_x$. But i still have question regarding it. i have edited the question to be more clear, can you please take a look again. Sorry about that.

Comment: @LittleRookie, there is nothing in the definition of $p_x$ (similarly $p_{x-1}$) about eventually hitting any state. $\tau_0$ could be infinite (i.e., never hitting 0) and still $\tau_{x} < \tau_0$ holds if $\tau_x < \infty$, that is, it will hold in this case if you hit $x$ at some point before being absorbed (assuming $x \neq 0$ or N).

Comment: my point is that the probability corresponds to an outcome of the experiment, there is no such outcome that stops at a non-absorption point.

Comment: @LittleRookie, there is nothing in these arguments that require we stop at a non-absorption state. I don't know what is giving you that impression. As I mentioned, the event hitting x before 0, include both cases where you hit x and then hit 0, as well as the case where you hit x and never hit 0. Both outcomes are included, and our arguments are agnostic to that. You can try to separate the two cases, if it bothers you, but there no need.

Comment: I should also add that $\tau_x < \tau_0$ is the precise event that perhaps we should stick with. Maybe , saying that it means "hitting x before 0" is what is confusing you. I used it for convenience.  Note that it doesn't mean "hitting x and then hitting 0". What you wrote in your question " $p_{x-1}$ is the probability of starting from $x−1$, reaching $x$ without hitting 0, and eventually hit 0." is not correct. The part "eventually hit 0" is not part of the event. Removing that last bit makes it OK.

Comment: My question is still the same as before, why does $p_{x-1}$ is USED as the P(trials start from $x-1$ and STOP at $x$). Do you understand my question?

Comment: $p_{x-1}$ is the not the probability of starting at $x-1$ and stopping at $x$. It is the probability of hitting $x$ before 0, starting at $x-1$. I have never assumed that the process stops at $x$. I might add more details. If you look at my argument, the tricky part is the second factor which uses strong Markov property, not the first which seems to be what you are focusing on.

Comment: i agree it is indeed not starting at $x-1$ and stopping at $x$, but as the question is explained to me during class, it was described as " As you move down 1 step, the probability is q, as you move from $x-1$ to $x$ without hitting $0$, the probability is then multiplied by $p_{x-1}$, as you move from $x$ to $x+1$ without hitting $0$, the probability is then multiplied by $p_{x}$.

Comment: What you wrote is fine as intuitive (dare I say hand-waving) argument. You decompose the path into two pieces, if you moved to x-1 (which has prob. q), in order to hit x+1 before 0, you have to hit x before zero first (path 1), then starting from x, you have to hit x+1 before hitting zero (path 2). This starting from x, as if the process starts afresh, uses strong Markov property. I have included all the glorious details (if I haven't made a typo, mistake, etc.)

Comment: I understand now, thanks.

Comment: @LittleRookie, no problem.

Comment: Sorry for this late comment, when u mention that "decompose the path into two pieces" , do you mean decompose the path into two different paths? Because it is impossible to that path 1 consists of only finite number of steps.

Comment: @LittleRookie, no I meant two pieces of the same path. You have to pass through x to get to x+1 and that point splits the path into what was before it and what comes after. Path 1 can be finite, it can even have length one (just move from x-1 to x).

Comment: For the finite sub-path from $x-1$ to $x$, why the probability of moving from $x-1$ to $x$ without hitting $0$ is $p_{x-1}$? I thought $p_{x-1}$ is the probability that the path of infinite length starting from $x-1$ and reaching $x$ without hitting $0$. In that sense, the second piece (infinite length) having the probability $p_x$ is right.

Comment: Really not sure what you mean by finite versus infinite path. There is nothing infinite here, the events that you are looking at all involve hitting certain states in finite time.  (What happens afterward is of no concern to us.)  Look at the 2nd displayed equ. and the discussion after that under More details in my response. Also look at the definition of $p_x$ and replace $x$ with $x-1$ and think of what the definition means in that case.